# Can't Remote Desktop to a computer from another network

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, windows-firewall

We have an office network with Windows machines. We use Fortinet's VPN to access the network remotely, and open a remote desktop connection to our local computers. We have this one computer that won't accept Remote Desktop connections from the VPN.

From the VPN we can open a Remote Desktop connection to other computers. From our office LAN we can open a Remote Desktop connection to the problematic computer. We can ping from the VPN to the problematic computer, and yet we can't open a Remote Desktop connection.

Looking at the Windows Firewall settings didn't help - Remote Desktop has an inbound rule that allows access from all networks - public, private and domain.

Comment: There's not a machine in the local network with the same IP address as the remote/vpn network is there? (are the two networks on different ranges?)

Comment: Is that even possible without the machines notifying you about it?

Comment: Yes because they exist in two seperate private networks. You only get notified (sometimes) when two machines connected to the **same network** are set to the same IP. If you have Network A, with machine A-20 as 192.168.1.20 and network B with B-20 as 192.168.1.20, there's no issue (they are seperate private networks) **until** machine A21 connects to network B through a vpn and tries to access 192.168.1.20 in network B. (There's no awareness between A-20 and B-20 to detect identical IP addresses)

Comment: The machine connected to the VPN is has a VPN address, which is a different network. Its original address is our Wifi network, which also has a different address range.